# failed to access script from master page , but from Content page is all correct

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, reference, master-pages

Weired because it shouldn't matter how things done in Server side.

Master Page:

```
<head runat="server>  
    <script src="jquery/jquery-2.0.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PageHeadPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

Content Page:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PageHeadPlaceHolder" Runat="Server">
<link href="prettyPhoto315/css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="prettyPhoto315/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
        });
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

though client finds **jquery-2.0.2.min.js**  it fails to execute `$(document).ready...`
saying **'$ reference is not defined'**.

---

I Tried:

1. when i move the `<script src="jquery/jquery-2.0.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` to the content page... everything works right.
2. using `<script src="~/jquery/jquery-2.0.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
   the script is not found at all.
3. same happens if i move a `<link href="prettyPhoto315/css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />` to the master page,  the page does not show the specific style sheet.
4. when checking the output HTML, it all seem correct in the right order.
   i uploaded the output HTML to http://pastebin.com/ULi228BF

please help asap. thanks.

Comment: Make sure your script name is `jquery-2.0.2.min.js`. And it is located in that directory.

Comment: it is... both .master and .aspx files are in the same directory, hence their relative paths are same

Answer (score 1):

Do it declaratively in the master page by dragging the jQuery files from Solution Explorer window to the code view of the mark-up. Then see if it works and compare the two versions of the paths.

Answer (score -1):

GOT IT! OMG  KNEW it is something that shouldn't matter
IrishChieftain post got me to test the pages again, and found the problem!

Apperantly the `jquery.magnifier.js` library i used is incompatible with jQuery 1.6+
are is breaking `jQuery` script for some reason overriding

therefore:

```
<script src="jquery/jquery-2.0.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="windowfiles/dhtmlwindow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.magnifier.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(); </script>
```

wont work...
while:

```
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.3.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="windowfiles/dhtmlwindow.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.magnifier.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery-2.0.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(); </script>
```

does!

hope someone can make use of this info.
and thanks for the help.